# Can I link two elements in svg such that mousing over one changes an attribute of the other?

Tags: xml, svg, mouseevent, mouseover

Let's say I have 2 svg elements, a circle and some text:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1500 1500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <circle cx="1000" cy="1000" r="50" />
    <text x="900" y="900" style="font-size:100px">Test</text>
</svg>
```

Next, I want the text to appear only when I mouseover it, which I can do like so:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1500 1500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <circle cx="1000" cy="1000" r="50" />
    <text x="900" y="900" style="font-size:100px" opacity="0" onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '1');" onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0');">Test</text>
</svg>
```

Is it possible to link the circle and the text such that hovering over either one causes the text to become visible, while keeping the circle visible in all cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Robert Longson's helpful comment, here is a JavaScript solution:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1500 1500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">  
    <circle id="circle" cx="1000" cy="1000" r="50" />
    <text id="text" x="900" y="900" style="font-size:100px" opacity="0">Test</text>
    <script>
        <![CDATA[
            var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
            var text = document.getElementById("text");
            circle.addEventListener("mouseover",function(event){
                text.setAttribute('opacity',1);
            })
            circle.addEventListener("mouseout",function(event){
                text.setAttribute('opacity',0);
            })
        ]]>
    </script>
</svg>
```